# Is it possible to use systemd on Gentoo with hardened/selinux profile?

Tags: linux, gentoo, selinux, hardening

Or I need to create custom profile which will combine settings from **hardened/selinux** and **systemd** profiles? Because I even can't unmask *sys-apps/systemd* or set USE-flag *systemd* on some package.

Comment: Not an answer, but maybe relevant: https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1029642-start-0.html